# install_driver(mysql) failed: Unable to get DBI state function. DBI not loaded

Tags: mysql, perl, sles11, otrs

I installed OTRS from a rpm and the web installer `/orts/installer.pl` stops with:

> Error during AJAX communication. Status: error, Error: Internal Server
>   Error

Apache error_log

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Unable to get DBI state function. DBI
>   not loaded.

`/opt/otrs/bin/otrs.CheckModules.pl`

> DBD::mysql.......................FAILED! Not all prerequisites for this module correctly installed.
>   YAML::XS.........................Not installed! (required - use "perl -MCPAN -e shell;" - )

But `sudo zypper install perl-DBD-mysql-4.021-27.2.x86_64.rpm` has `Nothing to do.` and mysql configuration is set as the [manual](http://doc.otrs.org/3.2/en/html/installation.html#installation-on-suse) requested.

System is SLES 11 SP2  (x86_64) and special thing: No internet connection!

I guess the question is: **Why doesn't perl find DBI:mysql while it's installed?**

**Update**

[list_the_installed_modules](http://www.perlhowto.com/list_the_installed_modules)

> /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Bundle/DBI.pm
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/mysql.pm
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm

Could I have installed the wrong rpm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out `perl-DBD-mysql-4.021-27.2.x86_64.rpm` was to new for my perl version. I had a look at the package list for [SLES 11 PS2 (x86_64)](https://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=server&version=11&service_pack=sp2&architecture=x86_64&package_name=index_all) and learnt it should be `perl-DBD-mysql-4.008-4.3.x86_64.rpm`. So I removed the installed one:

```
sudo zypper remove perl-DBD-mysql
```

Googled and installed `perl-DBD-mysql-4.008-4.3.x86_64.rpm`.´

Now it works!

Comment: Great, so where did you get the other one in the first place? You should not install RPMs off Google - that is kind of scar - you should use the SLES repos or the build service (and then some trusted repo) instead. DBD::mysql IS in the main SLES repositories.

Comment: @Mike yes, it is scary. Found it on http://rpm.pbone.net/

Answer (score 0):

This error message does mean that perl can't find the DBD::mysql module. So if the rpm package is installed, this leads me to think that you might not be using the system perl.

Can you show us:

```
which perl
```

and also:

```
/usr/bin/perl /opt/otrs/bin/otrs.CheckModules.pl
```

In general it is not a good idea to install your own perl on top of the existing system perl. This can break other installed packages that expect a certain perl version.

If you want to use different perls on your system, use tools like [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv) or [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl)

Also, OTRS typically works with the system perl on SLES 11.

Comment: Thank you. There is only on perl installed and using `/usr/bin/perl` tells me the same. I have another SLES 11 SP2 (x86_64) running otrs. I am just trying to move it to another server.

Comment: So could it be that DBI is not listed as a prerequisite correctly? Can you do `zypper install "perl(DBI)"`?

Comment: `'perl-DBI' providing 'perl(DBI)' is already installed.`